# How to use an IP address for a multi-site in Drupal 8?

Tags: multisite, drupal-8

[This](https://www.drupal.org/node/1693508) url seems to claim that it's not possible. But also the workarounds on the site doesn't work, and the information is dated. So my question is... why does this work in Drupal 8, when you put it in the sites.php file:

```
$sites = array(
    // URL ==> path
    'test.localhost'   => 'default',
    'test2.localhost' => 'somepath',
);
```

But not this:

```
$sites = array(
    // URL ==> path
    'test.localhost'   => 'default',
    '127.0.0.1' => 'somepath',
);
```

And how would I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug dont go that way. You will have to setup additional Virtual Host and setup drupal there. You can also partially link another site and modify only configuration - but it is a filesystem related opration not Drupal nor Apache/Nginx operation.